# How to filter API data in sanity.io using react.js?

Tags: reactjs, sanity, groq

Hello I am new to the community and learning how things work here. Please try to understand through my broken English.

suppose there are 200 data in API, but I just wanted to pull any 4 random data to frontend. To be more clear the data are blog posts from **sanity.io** using groq ql in React.js. Here is the code which displays all the data from the API. I have tried `slice` function but did not worked.

```
const SideBarBlog = () => {
  const [postData, setPost] = useState(null);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    sanityClient
      .fetch(
        `*[_type=="post"]{
        title,
        slug,
        mainImage{
          asset->{
            _id,
            url
          },
          alt,
          
        }
      }`
      )
      .then((data) => setPost(data))
      .then((data) => console.log(postData))

      .catch(console.error);
  }, []);

return (
    <>
      {postData &&
        postData.map((post, index) => (
       
            <div className="row sidebar-blog mb-4 p-3" key={index}>
              <div className="col-md-8">
                {/* sideblog title */}
                <p className="sidebolg-blogtitle mb-1">{post.title}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
         
        ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default SideBarBlog;
```

Comment: in `.then((data) => setPost(data))`, you can do anything you want before `setPost`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you set ur state with the posts, you can access a random post in the array like this:

```
const postData = [{ post: "some post obj" }, { post: "another post obj" },  ];

const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * postsData.length); 
postData[random] //this returns a  random post
```

With this you can now access random posts and create a new array of length 4 or however you wish to do it